# Convert rows to columns in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert rows to columns in MS SQL server.

Example DB Table:

```
**ID    PersonID    Person201Code   Person201Value**
  1     1           CurrentIdNo     0556
  2     1           FirstName       Queency
  3     1           LastName        Sablan
```

The query result should be like this:

```
**CurrentIdNo     FirstName         LastName**
  0556            Queency             Sablan
```

I tried using PIVOT but it only return null on row values:

```
SELECT CurrentIdNo, FirstName, LastName
FROM

(
  SELECT ID, PersonId, Person201Code, Person201Value
  FROM HRPerson201
) src
PIVOT
(
  MAX (ID)
  FOR Person201Code in (CurrentIdNo, Firstname, LastName))
 pvt;
```

How can I successfully convert rows to columns in MS SQL server?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `ID` from pivot source query and add `Person201Value` pivot aggregate 
instead of `ID`

```
SELECT CurrentIdNo,
       FirstName,
       LastName
FROM   (SELECT PersonId,
               Person201Code,
               Person201Value
        FROM   HRPerson201) src
       PIVOT ( Max (Person201Value)
             FOR Person201Code IN (CurrentIdNo,
                                   Firstname,
                                   LastName)) pvt;
```

- [**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7a15/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT personid,Person201Code,Person201Value
   FROM #pivot) Sales
  PIVOT(max(Person201Value)
   FOR Person201Code in (CurrentIdNo, Firstname, LastName))
  AS PivotSales;
```