# SQL Server - Transposing Rows to Columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

We have a table in our MSSQL database, that store Office Person relation ship data. The table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE (
    OfficeID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    PersonID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    Designation VARCHAR(20)
)
```

The table will have value

```
    E1F5ECA9-7D5A-4580-AA7D-0003A582F286|E1F5ECA9-7D5A-3580-AA7D-0003A582F286|Manager
    E1F5ECA9-7D5A-4580-AA7D-0003A582F286|E1F5ECA9-7D5A-3580-AA7D-0003A582F286|Engineer
    E2F5ECA9-7D5A-4580-AA7D-0003A582F286|E2F5ECA9-7D5A-3580-AA7D-0003A582F286|Manager
    E2F5ECA9-7D5A-4580-AA7D-0003A582F286|E2F5ECA9-7D5A-3580-AA7D-0003A582F286|Engineer
```

What I want to get is each office can have only one Manager and one Engineer. The output I am expecting is

```
OfficeID|Manager ID| Engineer ID|
E1F5ECA9-7D5A-4580-AA7D-0003A582F286|E1F5ECA9-7D5A-3580-AA7D-0003A582F286| E1F5ECA9-7D5A-3580-AA7D-0003A582F286
E2F5ECA9-7D5A-4580-AA7D-0003A582F286|E2F5ECA9-7D5A-3580-AA7D-0003A582F286|E2F5ECA9-7D5A-3580-AA7D-0003A582F286
```

How can i form the query for getting the data in this format?

Regards,

John

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert rows to columns in MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451934/convert-rows-to-columns-in-ms-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    OfficeId
  , ManagerId  = max(case when Designation = 'Manager'  then PersonId end)
  , EngineerId = max(case when Designation = 'Engineer' then PersonId end)
from t
group by OfficeId
```

or using `pivot()`:

```
select
    OfficeId
  , ManagerId = Manager
  , EngineerId = Engineer
from t
pivot (max(PersonId) for Designation in ([Manager],[Engineer])) p
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OTFBIS66929